# Override form default post using JQuery issue

Tags: jquery

I am in a bit situation here. I have to override the form submit using JQuery. One of my forms is posting using form Post using a button using a default method. I have added an ajax before to validate the form elements from database using ajax and this action need to be performed before the form submits.

I have used `.one()` to prevent the default form post and added my ajax along with it. This is my code:

```
//submit the form and prevent default submit
    $(form_selector).one('submit', function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            this_.triggerAjax($(this));
    });
 //its a class function
triggerAjax: function(){
    $ajax({
        ..
        ..
        success: function(res){
          if(res.success){
             showAlert()
          return false; //do not allow form to submit
         }
         else
         {
          $(form_selector).submit()
         }
        }
     });
}
```

Now, I am able to prevent the form post by default but if I have to retrigger the form submit using Jquery, the form is posting using the default method. How do I prevent it?

This is an old form and I don't want to changes everything that has been already done on a form post. I only want my ajax to run before the form post and if ajax returns `true` then do not post the form and if Ajax returns 'false' only then post the form. Also, if ajax is not triggered, maybe due to its condition (required variables are not available) is not met then allow me to retrigger the button.

Can anyone help?
Please feel free to ask questions if you need more understanding..

I am using Yii1 as framework and Jquery for Ajax

Comment: Why don't you use `.on()` instead of `.one()`?

Comment: I had used `.on()` earlier but when I submitted the form using the ajax call back on success. The form submit process went in an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal runnable and repucable example?